# I want to limit the page number pagination on bottom it based on the records from database. I gave condition but it not working. please check it

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, vue.js

Here is my code and last i gave condition for page link. offset=4 i fix page link to 4. for example < 1 2 3 4 > I want this output. but my output is < 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 > the page link also expand when records increase i want to fix it.

```
<div class="text-center" v-if="totalPage > 1">
                    <nav aria-label="Page navigation example">
                        <ul class="pagination">
                            <li class="page-item" :class="{disabled:filter.page <= 1}">
                                <a class="page-link" v-if="filter.page <=1">{{__("Previous")}}</a>
                                <a class="page-link" href="#" v-if="filter.page > 1" v-on:click="changePage(filter.page-1,$event)">{{__("Previous")}}</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="page-item" v-if="p >= (filter.page-3) && p <= (filter.page+3)" :class="{active: p == filter.page}" v-for="p in totalPage" @click="changePage(p,$event)">
                                <a class="page-link" href="#">@{{p}}</a></li>
                            <li class="page-item" :class="{disabled:filter.page >= totalPage}">
                                <a v-if="filter.page >= totalPage" class="page-link">{{__("Next")}}</a>
                                <a href="#" class="page-link" v-if="filter.page < totalPage" v-on:click="changePage(filter.page+1,$event)">{{__("Next")}}</a>
                            </li>
                            <pagination v-if="pagination.@{{p}} >1" :pagination="pagination" :offset="4" @paginate="fetchPosts()" </pagination>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
                </div>
```

Comment: Also take a look at the [database side of pagination](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/pagination) to do this correctly.

Comment: please check the laravel pagination how we can make it correctly using paginate() method in eloquent